# Multithreading with NHibernate and MVVM

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, mvvm

I am starting a thread at the loading of each windows/form so there is no freeze. Everything working fine but the problem is when the user is changing of windows before the end of the thread ( the thread returning an observableCollection which is bind to a datagrid ). Does there is a way to detect if a thread is running before change windows and kill it ?

The error message I get :

```
NHibernate.Exception.GenericADOEception: could not execute the query.

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

ViewModel Code :

```
public GererArticleViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IMarqueService marqueService, IFormatService formatService, IArticleService articleService)
{
    _formatService = formatService;
    _marqueService = marqueService;
    _articleService = articleService;
    _navigationService = navigationService;

    LoadedEvent = new RelayCommand(Loaded);
}

    #region Commande
    public ICommand LoadedEvent { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Fonction
    private void Loaded()
    {
        _articleService.AsyncRetrieveAll(LoadedCallback);
    }

    private void LoadedCallback(IList<Article> list)
    {
        ListeArticles = new ObservableCollection<Article>(list);
    }
    #endregion
```

The property ListeArticles is bind to a DataGrid

Nhibernate Service code :

```
    public void AsyncRetrieveAll(Action<IList<Article>> callback)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var result = _session.Query<Article>().ToList();

            DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(callback, result);
        }).Start();
    }
```

Sorry about my english, french is my native language.

Comment: Your english is surely better than my french!

Comment: Ahah, French is a very hard language to learn

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate Session is not thread safe, so each must have its own Session.